# C# Fast way to create DTO from WCF proxy?

Tags: c#, wcf, proxy

I have WCF Proxy and want to create exact DTOs from it, but if I write it out manually there will probably be some "human errors" that I often do not want to spend my time on. How I can create something like this:

```
public class MyDto
{
    public string Val1 {get;set;}
    public int Val2 {get;set;}
}
```

from proxy one? Also, I do not want to use AutoMapper because library should be as much independent as possible.

Comment: Personally, DTOs are a waste of time.  Use a _canonical data model_ and do away with DTOs;  multiple definions of entites; accidental or intentional data fidelity loss and time spent performing data transformations.  http://soapatterns.org/design_patterns/canonical_schema